# Using Scheme, how do I merge more than two lists

Tags: list, merge, scheme

I'm trying to merge multiple lists together in scheme. I have to make sure that the final list is sorted, but luckily that won't be too hard, as the given lists must be sorted. On the flip side, I also have to check if the lists are sorted.

Here's the code I have so far :

/* mergeALot isn't finished; for some reason I get a grammar error on the "and" as well as the "else". Additionally, I don't know how to check to see if the first element is a list or not (to stop iteration) */

```
(define (mergeALot a)
(cond (and
     ordered? (car a)
     ordered? (cadr a))
      (mergeALot(cons
                (merge (car a)(cadr a))
                (cdr (cdr a))))
(else
 (display "Some lists are not ordered"))))


(define (ordered? lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #t)
        ((eq? (length lst) 1) #t)
  ((> (car (cdr lst)) (car lst))
    (ordered? (cdr lst)))
  (else #f))
 )

(define (merge a b)
  (cond ((null? a) b)
    ((null? b) a)
    ((>= (car a) (car b))
     (cons (car b) (merge a (cdr b))))
    (else
     (cons (car a) (merge (cdr a) b)))))
```

Comment: You are lacking parentheses around `cond` term. Since you are only having one consequent you might as well use `if`. Know that `ordered?` without using parentheses like `(ordered? (car a))` evaluates to a procedure and it is a true value since it isn't `#f`, but you're not actually using the procedure.

Comment: Thank you. I'm running into another error now though; every time I try to use an else statement I get the error "else: not allowed as an expression in:"  even in the case of the most basic if/else program I could think of,  `(define (test a)
(if (= 1 2)
   (#t)
(else (#f))))`

Comment: If not homework, `(list-sort < (apply append lists))` Like: http://eval.ironscheme.net/?id=173

Comment: @i'mpotent There is no `else` in an `if`. It's simply `(if predicate consequent alternative)` eg `(if (<= x 3) "You have three or less" "you have more than three")`

Answer (score 0):

This looks a bit like schoolwork, but I'll give you the basic idea. You will likely get a list of lists. Since the terminology gets a bit out of hand, lets call the list of lists unmerged-lists. If there is only one list in unmerged-lists, then you're done! But say there are two. There are two lists in unmerged-lists. Then you need a function that consumes the two lists, and  produces merged result. Then, I'd have to update unmerged-lists. If my function was called: merge-sorted, I'd likely have:

```
(cons (my-merge (first unmerged-lists) (second unmerged-lists))
      (rest (rest unmerged-lists)))
```

which you would keep doing until unmerged-lists only has one element, at which point you would stop because you cannot take (rest (rest list)) when the list only has one element. Hopefully you can get the recursion!

Comment: Are "first" and "second" equivalent to "car" and "car cdr" or am I missing something

Comment: I believe "car" is equivalent to "cons" and "cdr" is the same as "rest" I don't think there are other forms of "first" and "second" though, like, they stand for the first and second elements of the list

Comment: car refers to the first element, and cdr indeed is the same as "rest" (with "car cdr" meaning "the first element of the rest"). Are you sure that this is scheme grammar? I tried looking up "first" and "second" and couldnt find anything. Regardless, thanks for your help, it turned a bunch of lightbulbs on in my head.

Comment: Ohh, it might be because I'm used to the Racket dialect and never used "actual" scheme. I thought of a funny way to do this, you can append all the lists and then run a sort function!

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic methods to do a multi-way merge.

The first method is to merge the lists in succession: Merge the first two lists. Then merge the third list into the merge of the first two lists. Then merge the fourth list into the merge of the first three lists. And so on.

The second method uses a heap, and is much faster. Make a heap with one node per list, ordered by the smallest item in each list. Then repeatedly extract the smallest item from the heap, and re-heap.

Comment: Thanks; I tried to implement the first way, but I ended up with a grammar error on the "and". I also don't know how to check if a given element is a list or not. Can you take a look at the code and lead me a bit further? This stuff is really confusing when you've only coded with java...

Comment: You're missing some parentheses, which is causing the problem at "and". The opposite of null? is pair?, which can be used to determine if an object is a list. I don't have time now, but I'll do a multi-way merge at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com) next week.

Comment: There's actually a third method that I though about after writing my original answer. The code for all three methods is available at [ideone](http://ideone.com/o2iUf8); you might enjoy figuring out for yourself how it works. The write-up will appear next Tuesday at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2016/03/29/multi-way-merge); that link will become effective next Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 3 sorted lists:

```
unmerged: ((1 2 3) (3 5 6) (1 4 5))
```

#### Find the minimal value

Find the list having the least first element. In the following, I'll call it  `min-list` and `min` is the first element of that list:

```
min-list: (1 2 3)
min: 1
```

#### Recursive call

Cons the `min` value to the result of a recursive call to `merge-all` with the same `unmerged` list, except that you replace `min-list` by `(cdr min-list)`; all other lists are kept as they are. In your example, it is as-if you called:

```
(cons 1 (merge-all '((2 3) (3 5 6) (1 4 5))))
```

The way you compute the recursive `unmerged` list could be for example as follows:

```
(map (lambda (u) (if (eq? u min-list) (cdr u) u)) unmerged)
```

#### Termination condition

You should ignore any empty list in your `unmerged` list, and stop the recursion as soon as all your lists are empty. Alternatively, always remove empty lists from `unmerged` and stop when `unmerged` itself is empty.